# TSV to DataFrame conversion error: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to org.apache.spark.sql.types.UTF8String

Tags: scala, csv, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

So I have been trying for a while to write a simple parser for Postgres dump files. But every time I run it, I come across this exception.

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to org.apache.spark.sql.types.UTF8String
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkSqlSerializer2$$anonfun$createSerializationFunction$1.apply(SparkSqlSerializer2.scala:334)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkSqlSerializer2$$anonfun$createSerializationFunction$1.apply(SparkSqlSerializer2.scala:227)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.Serializer2SerializationStream.writeValue(SparkSqlSerializer2.scala:70)
  at org.apache.spark.storage.DiskBlockObjectWriter.write(BlockObjectWriter.scala:207)
  at org.apache.spark.util.collection.WritablePartitionedIterator$$anon$3.writeNext(WritablePartitionedPairCollection.scala:104)
  at org.apache.spark.util.collection.ExternalSorter.spillToPartitionFiles(ExternalSorter.scala:375)
  at org.apache.spark.util.collection.ExternalSorter.insertAll(ExternalSorter.scala:208)
  at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.SortShuffleWriter.write(SortShuffleWriter.scala:62)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:70)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:41)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:70)
  at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:213)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I found this [similar issue](https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv/issues/64) reported by someone. And since it was a closed issue, I tried to use their code to fix mine, but that's still the case. Here's what I have,

```
// Taken mainly from: https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/databricks/spark/csv/CsvRelation.scala#L102
def getRdd(sqlContext: SQLContext, workDir: String, structType: StructType): RDD[Row] = {
  val len = structType.fields.size

  val rdd = sqlContext.sparkContext
    .textFile(workDir)
    .flatMap { line =>
      val colVals = line.split("\t", -1)

      if (colVals.size < len) None
      else {
        val rowArray = new Array[Any](len)

        breakable {
          colVals.zipWithIndex.foreach { case (colVal: Any, i: Int) =>
            val field = structType(i)
            colVal.castTo(field.dataType, field.nullable) match {
              case Success(v) => rowArray(i) = v
              case Failure(e) => None; break
            }
          }
        }
        Some(Row.fromSeq(rowArray))
      }
    }
  rdd
}
```

Here, `toCast` is a method to an implicit class for `String`. Here's the code for that.

```
// Taken mainly from: https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/databricks/spark/csv/util/TypeCast.scala
def castTo(castType: DataType, nullable: Boolean = true, treatEmptyValuesAsNulls: Boolean = false): Try[Any] = {
  val castedValue = {
    if (nullable && (s == null || s == "\\N" || (s == "" && treatEmptyValuesAsNulls)) && !castType.isInstanceOf[StringType]) Try(null)
    else {
      castType match {
        case _: BooleanType => Try(toBool)
        case _: ByteType => Try(s.toByte)
        case _: DateType => Try(Date.valueOf(s))
        case _: DoubleType => Try(s.toDouble)
        case _: FloatType => Try(s.toFloat)
        case _: IntegerType => Try(s.toInt)
        case _: LongType => Try(s.toLong)
        case _: ShortType => Try(s.toShort)
        case _: StringType => Try(s)
        case _: TimestampType => Try(Timestamp.valueOf(s))
        case _ => throw new RuntimeException(s"Unsupported type: ${castType.typeName}")
      }
    }
  }

  castedValue
}
```

Not sure what's going wrong but if anyone has any insights, that would be great. Thanks!

**Edit:** Sample data: I am not sure how to encode tabs here. So here's what a file can look like.

```
John\tDoe\t23\t\N
Jane\t\t\N\t2001-11-09
```

`\N` is how `null`s are dumped and of course, here, `\t` represent TABs.

Comment: Please provide some sample data and version of Spark. Also are you using Spark-csv? if yes then version for that too is also required.

Comment: @Sumit: I am not using Spark-CSV. Just found a similar error in one of their bug tickets. Otherwise, I am using Spark 1.41 with Scala 2.10.4.

Comment: So why not simply set separator in spark-csv?

Comment: Because it doesn't recognize `\N` as `null`s and keeps throwing a `NumberFormatException`.

Comment: Isn't a custom format an overkill?  Passing data through `sed` should do just fine. Or even better setting `NULL` parameter when you call `COPY`.

Comment: The dump file we get is not really in our control. It's just a file we get which is big enough that we can't use a single machine, hence, no `sed`.